# Nodata message with React 0.13.3 and react-highcharts 3.0.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I'm working with react-highcharts. It works perfectly except nodata state.
I need to display 'No data available' message when chart has empty data.

I have check no-data-to-display.js of official highcharts but it doesn't work with React.
I would like to make a result like this: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/no-data-to-display/no-data-pie/

```
import React from 'react';
import Highcharts from 'react-highcharts/dist/bundle/highcharts';
require('highcharts-no-data-to-display');

class MyChart extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.state = this._getInitialState(props);
    }
    static chartColors() {
        return [
        '#04a5af', '#4a6cb4', '#2d4665', '#76b5db', '#b4dcee','#cae9de','#24a9b2','#48d0ae','#2a2b32', '#5065ae'
        ]
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
        this.setState(this._getInitialState(newProps));
    }

    _getInitialState(props) {
        return {
            chartConfig:
            {
                colors: MyChart.chartColors(),
                chart: {
                    type: 'column',
                    events: {
                        load: function(event) {
                            event.target.reflow();
                        }
                    }
                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: props.title
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    title: {
                        text: '',
                        style: {
                            fontSize: '12px'
                        }
                    },
                    labels:{
                        style:{
                            fontSize: '12px'
                        }
                    },
                    dateTimeLabelFormats : {
                        second : '%H:%M',
                        minute : '%H:%M',
                        hour : '%H:%M',
                        day : '%e-$b-%y',
                        week : '%e',
                        month : '%e',
                        year : '%e'
                    },
                    alternateGridColor: '#FAFAFA',
                    startOnTick: true,
                    endOnTick: true,
                    categories: [],
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: props.yTitle?props.yTitle: ""
                    },
                    stackLabels: {
                        enabled: false,
                        style: {
                            fontWeight: 'bold',
                            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                        }
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    align: 'center',
                    y: 15,
                    floating: false,
                    backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
                    shadow: false
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                        stacking: 'normal',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: false,
                            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                            style: {
                                textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                noData: {
                        position: {
                            "x": 0,
                            "y": 0,
                            "align": "center",
                            "verticalAlign": "middle"
                        }
                },
                series: props.series


            }

        };

    }



    render() {


        return (
            <div refs="wa-chart">
                <Highcharts config={this.state.chartConfig} ref="chart" isPureConfig={true} />
            </div>);
    }
}



export default MyChart;
```

I am using `react` 0.13.3, `react-highcharts` version 3.0.0 and `highcharts-no-data-to-display` version 0.1.2

Comment: Have you tried using [the official Highcharts solution for ReactJS](http://www.highcharts.com/blog/192-use-highcharts-to-create-charts-in-react)? There is an example for using modules with Highcharts.

Answer (score 3):

Your imports should look like this.

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import NoDataToDisplay from 'highcharts/modules/no-data-to-display';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';

NoDataToDisplay(Highcharts);
```

Define your options to have a noData message.

```
const options = {
lang: {
      noData: props.noDataMessage,
    },
    noData: {
      style: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: '15px',
        color: '#303030',
      },
    },
};
```

Use this options in your highcharts.

```
<HighchartsReact
   highcharts={Highcharts}
   options={options}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/kirjs/react-highcharts
tips: Using highcharts modules/add-ons like exporting, data, etc. (demo)

eg:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Highcharts from 'react-highcharts/dist/bundle/highcharts';
require('highcharts-no-data-to-display')(ReactHighcharts.Highcharts)

class MyChart extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.state = this._getInitialState(props);
    }
    static chartColors() {
        return [
        '#04a5af', '#4a6cb4', '#2d4665', '#76b5db', '#b4dcee','#cae9de','#24a9b2','#48d0ae','#2a2b32', '#5065ae'
        ]
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
        this.setState(this._getInitialState(newProps));
    }

    _getInitialState(props) {
        return {
            chartConfig:
            {
                colors: MyChart.chartColors(),
                chart: {
                    type: 'column',
                    events: {
                        load: function(event) {
                            event.target.reflow();
                        }
                    }
                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: props.title
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    title: {
                        text: '',
                        style: {
                            fontSize: '12px'
                        }
                    },
                    labels:{
                        style:{
                            fontSize: '12px'
                        }
                    },
                    dateTimeLabelFormats : {
                        second : '%H:%M',
                        minute : '%H:%M',
                        hour : '%H:%M',
                        day : '%e-$b-%y',
                        week : '%e',
                        month : '%e',
                        year : '%e'
                    },
                    alternateGridColor: '#FAFAFA',
                    startOnTick: true,
                    endOnTick: true,
                    categories: [],
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: props.yTitle?props.yTitle: ""
                    },
                    stackLabels: {
                        enabled: false,
                        style: {
                            fontWeight: 'bold',
                            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                        }
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    align: 'center',
                    y: 15,
                    floating: false,
                    backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
                    shadow: false
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                        stacking: 'normal',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: false,
                            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                            style: {
                                textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                lang:{
                  noData: 'no data!'
                },
                noData: {
                        position: {
                            "x": 0,
                            "y": 0,
                            "align": "center",
                            "verticalAlign": "middle"
                        }
                },
                series: props.series


            }

        };

    }



    render() {


        return (
            <div refs="wa-chart">
                <Highcharts config={this.state.chartConfig} ref="chart" isPureConfig={true} />
            </div>);
    }
}



export default MyChart;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React from 'react';
import Highcharts from 'react-highcharts/dist/bundle/highcharts';
require('highcharts-no-data-to-display')(Highcharts.Highcharts)

class MyChart extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.state = this._getInitialState(props);
    }
    static chartColors() {
        return [
        '#04a5af', '#4a6cb4', '#2d4665', '#76b5db', '#b4dcee','#cae9de','#24a9b2','#48d0ae','#2a2b32', '#5065ae'
        ]
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
        this.setState(this._getInitialState(newProps));
    }

    _getInitialState(props) {
        return {
            chartConfig:
            {
                colors: MyChart.chartColors(),
                chart: {
                    type: 'column',
                    events: {
                        load: function(event) {
                            event.target.reflow();
                        }
                    }
                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: props.title
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    title: {
                        text: '',
                        style: {
                            fontSize: '12px'
                        }
                    },
                    labels:{
                        style:{
                            fontSize: '12px'
                        }
                    },
                    dateTimeLabelFormats : {
                        second : '%H:%M',
                        minute : '%H:%M',
                        hour : '%H:%M',
                        day : '%e-$b-%y',
                        week : '%e',
                        month : '%e',
                        year : '%e'
                    },
                    alternateGridColor: '#FAFAFA',
                    startOnTick: true,
                    endOnTick: true,
                    categories: [],
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: props.yTitle?props.yTitle: ""
                    },
                    stackLabels: {
                        enabled: false,
                        style: {
                            fontWeight: 'bold',
                            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                        }
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    align: 'center',
                    y: 15,
                    floating: false,
                    backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
                    shadow: false
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                        stacking: 'normal',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: false,
                            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                            style: {
                                textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                lang:{
                  noData: 'no data!'
                },
                noData: {
                        position: {
                            "x": 0,
                            "y": 0,
                            "align": "center",
                            "verticalAlign": "middle"
                        }
                },
                series: props.series


            }

        };

    }



    render() {


        return (
            <div refs="wa-chart">
                <Highcharts config={this.state.chartConfig} ref="chart" isPureConfig={true} />
            </div>);
    }
}



export default MyChart;
```

Comment: Adding an explanation to how this code answers the question will help future visitors.

Comment: There was a error at the first answer;error code: import Highcharts from 'react-highcharts/dist/bundle/highcharts';
require('highcharts-no-data-to-display')(ReactHighcharts.Highcharts); right code: import Highcharts from 'react-highcharts/dist/bundle/highcharts';
require('highcharts-no-data-to-display')(Highcharts.Highcharts)

Comment: I feel stackover flow editor experience is very sulkly。I think github is very cool， maybe you do think it。

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I've created a npm package for this, just install it, and use it! this one ->
[react-highcharts-no-data-to-display](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-highcharts-no-data-to-display)

ANSWER: What you have to do is to add `(ReactHighcharts.Highcharts)` next to `require('highcharts-no-data-to-display')` quite easy right?

Just in case, if anyone is facing the same issue (trying to add the "no data" message in React-HighCharts). The steps are:

1. Install it! in a terminal run: `npm install highcharts-no-data-to-display --save`
2. In the react file that has the chart that you want to add the no-data message, you have to add `require('highcharts-no-data-to-display')(ReactHighcharts.Highcharts)` on the first lines
3. Furthermore, if you want to customize the text and position of the message. Add this:

>

```
lang:{
            noData: 'no data!' //the text to be displayed
          },
          noData: {
                  position: {
                      "x": 0, 
                      "y": 0,
                      "align": "center",
                      "verticalAlign": "middle"
                  }
          }
```

the full code of what @ittus is asking should be

```
import React from 'react';
import Highcharts from 'react-highcharts/dist/bundle/highcharts';
require('highcharts-no-data-to-display')(Highcharts.Highcharts)

class MyChart extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.state = this._getInitialState(props);
    }
    static chartColors() {
        return [
        '#04a5af', '#4a6cb4', '#2d4665', '#76b5db', '#b4dcee','#cae9de','#24a9b2','#48d0ae','#2a2b32', '#5065ae'
        ]
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
        this.setState(this._getInitialState(newProps));
    }

    _getInitialState(props) {
        return {
            chartConfig:
            {
                colors: MyChart.chartColors(),
                chart: {
                    type: 'column',
                    events: {
                        load: function(event) {
                            event.target.reflow();
                        }
                    }
                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: props.title
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    title: {
                        text: '',
                        style: {
                            fontSize: '12px'
                        }
                    },
                    labels:{
                        style:{
                            fontSize: '12px'
                        }
                    },
                    dateTimeLabelFormats : {
                        second : '%H:%M',
                        minute : '%H:%M',
                        hour : '%H:%M',
                        day : '%e-$b-%y',
                        week : '%e',
                        month : '%e',
                        year : '%e'
                    },
                    alternateGridColor: '#FAFAFA',
                    startOnTick: true,
                    endOnTick: true,
                    categories: [],
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: props.yTitle?props.yTitle: ""
                    },
                    stackLabels: {
                        enabled: false,
                        style: {
                            fontWeight: 'bold',
                            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                        }
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    align: 'center',
                    y: 15,
                    floating: false,
                    backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
                    shadow: false
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                        stacking: 'normal',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: false,
                            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                            style: {
                                textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                lang:{
                  noData: 'no data!'
                },
                noData: {
                        position: {
                            "x": 0,
                            "y": 0,
                            "align": "center",
                            "verticalAlign": "middle"
                        }
                },
                series: props.series


            }

        };

    }



    render() {


        return (
            <div refs="wa-chart">
                <Highcharts config={this.state.chartConfig} ref="chart" isPureConfig={true} />
            </div>);
    }
}



export default MyChart;
```

Answer (score 0):

import highchartsNoData from 'highcharts/modules/no-data-to-display';

highchartsNoData(Highcharts)

If you are not able to see no data message in React-Highchart try this will definitely work.